# My laptop keyboard and mousepad don't respond after suspesion on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: keyboard, dell, laptop, 18.10, responsiveness

My laptop keyboard and mousepad (not usb external) don't respond when I turn on my laptop after suspension. I noticed the caps lock key doesn't work either. I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

without success. My slow keys button is not turned on either. If I reboot the system then everything works fine, but the problem re appears when I suspend and turn on again my laptop.
I'm using ubuntu 18.10 on a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 Series, if you know any other solution please let me know!

Comment: 18.10 isn't xorg, it's wayland by default. please provide perfipheral specs. as well as the output for `lsusb -v`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Not sure about the peripheral specs. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, it's my laptop's keyboard and mousepad that's not working. Here's a link to the output of lsusb -v just in case 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1REouEpTu3yULB7_KRaFumppXM0RuG0vL

Comment: you need to edit your answer to include that instead. (make sure to format the text as code after pasting it) also that's specifically what I was reffering to : your mouse and your keyboard :  ...what are their model numbers? for example `g703` is a googlable model number

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. Not sure how to find the model number of my laptop's keyboard and mousepad. g703 appears to be an external mouse, my problem is with laptop's own mousepad and keyboard

Comment: you'll have to look on the laptop manufaturer's website. or if you're more savvy, you could open up your laptop and see what's written under the keyboard and the trackpad.